# Using the spread operator as parameter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

**What is the point of using the spread operator as parameter in`return withDefaultStatus(...)`?**

I've been staring and poking at this code for a while now and i can't figure something out.
At first i thought it's used as a condition, but now i'm totally confused.

PS1: I don't think it has anything to do with lodash, but i added it anyway.
PS2: The state is being passed from a React Component.

```
const {defaults} = require('lodash/fp')

const withDefaultStatus = defaults({
    isFinished: false,
    isPending: true,
    code: 0
});

const state = {
    isFinished: true,
    isMutation: false,
    isPending: false,
    lastUpdated: 1512730452993,
    queryCount: 5,
    status: 1,
    url: "https://",
}

function selectQueryStatus(state) {
    const {
        isFinished,
        isPending,
        status: code,
        lastUpdated,
        queryCount
    } = state || {};

    return withDefaultStatus({
        isFinished, isPending , ...code && { code, lastUpdated, queryCount }
    });
}

console.log(selectQueryStatus(state))
//output { isFinished: true, isPending: false, code: 1, lastUpdated: 512730452993, queryCount: 5 }
```

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri why was this closed as a dupe? OP is asking **why** spread is used, **not what** it is. He even identified "the three dots" as a spread operator, so why dupe it to a post asking what `...` is?

Comment: @Chris, the post does explain, what does it do which will answer as to why is it there. If you don't agree, I will remove the duplicate vote

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri Hmm, I don't think it really does. Anyway, when closing posts as dupes, don't link them to another dupe post. You might want to increase visibility to your own answers, but please use the canonical answer instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the following syntax

```
withDefaultStatus({
        isFinished, isPending , ...code && { code, lastUpdated, queryCount }
    });
```

The reason why Spread syntax is used is because, `code`, `lastUpdate` and `queryCount` values need to be passed to the object only when code is available. So essentially `…code && { code, lastUpdated, queryCount }` will return `code, lastUpdated, queryCount` when `code` is evaluated to `true`. And hence you entire object will become

```
 {
    isFinished,
    isPending ,
    code,
    lastUpdated,
    queryCount 
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for the explination! It was my initial thought aswell. But how can code be evaluated to `true` when code is an integer? Do you mean it is evaluated to `true` if it's NOT `undefined`?

Comment: If its not undefined or null